# how to sum positive (+) and negative (-) number in excel

Tags: excel

I have a Excel question. How do I sum the numbers in a column which has -1, 1, -2, 3, 1 in a way that it shows me two separate results? Here is the example of my desired ouput:

```
week    az  ca  tx  
week1   1    3   1
week2  -1   -1  -2
week3   1   -1   1

win     2    3   2
loss    1    2   2
```

i tried to use the auto sum in Excel but it gives me something like this:

```
win     1    1   0
```

could someone with Excel (does not mater what version) expertise help please?
i tried the =if(true value, and false but it does not work)

Thanks a lot. 
Joey

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it, and even if it were, it is on the wrong site. You want to ask this on [SU]. However, you should inspect the formulas in the sum cells, most likely they have included the wrong range. Your example input shows an empty line, perhaps the sum cells only counted the bottom cells, after the break? Still doesn't explain the sums you were given, but examining the sum cell formulas might give you enough clues to solve this yourself. There is not enough information here for anyone to solve it though, so you're going to have to post more.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Comment: NP, hope you get to the bottom of it. Judging by the title of your question, let me just say that the SUM(X) function in Excel, or using the `+` operator in Excel, will both handle negative numbers just fine. `SUM(A1:A2)` where A1=10 and A2=-5 will evaluate to 5, this has nothing to do with positive vs. negative numbers.

Comment: @L, yes that what i did originally. it works just fine. thanks for your time and input for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`sumif`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function to sum only positive or negative numbers.

For the wins:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B4, ">0")
```

For the loses:

```
=-1 * SUMIF(B2:B4, "<0")
```