# Sum currency columns with positive and negative values

Tags: google-sheets-api

Google Sheets:
I have data in a column that shows all positive currency values but they can be a buy or sell.

If I add the number 1 in a column 5 times and use the same sum I get 5 :

```
1
1
1
1
1
5
```

but if I change a value to -1 then I get and unexpected.

```
1
-1
1
1
1
3
```

I get 3

I am not sure why or how to correct this, thanks ahead

Comment: You need to use the function [SUMIFS](https://www.w3schools.com/googlesheets/google_sheets_sumifs.php)

Comment: What are you asking/expecting? How is a value marked as a buy or sell in your sheet? Do you want the second example in your question to sum to 5? Or do you want to ignore negative values and have it sum to 4?

Comment: Indeed, when I re-read the question it's pretty unclear, because `1+(-1)+1+1+1=3`, and you question does not say what you are expecting in this case.  My guess was 4, which you can achieve by using the SUMIFS function.  this works the same as in Excel, so explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927180/how-to-sum-positive-and-negative-number-in-excel

Comment: Can also include the expected behavior, not just the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.